# npm start error (spawn ENOENT, Failed at the nodetest1@0.0.0 start script.)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, npm

Trying to start with this tutorial: http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/. It uses node.js, express, monk, mongoDB and is a tutorial for new comers to node and express like me.

But after installing express and all the necessary dependencies and following the steps to the detail, when I try to run "npm start", I get the following error, and I really have no idea what's causing it after searching for a similar answer on stackoverflow:

Part 1 of the error on console: 
[image: Part1Error]

Part 2: 
[image]

npm-debug: 
[image]

Comment: What does `C:\node\nodetest1` contain?

Comment: Have you read `C:\node\nodetest1\npm-debug.log`? What doe it say?

Comment: Edited the post to add the npm-debug. Something wrong with the node ./bin/www in the package.json file, but I don't really know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Did you get any error during `"npm install"`?
If that is the case, try running it as admin. (In windows, open the command prompt as Administrator or if MAC/Linux, run `"sudo npm install"`)
If none of this works, run `"npm install npm -g"` and then continue.